# Why can "repo sync" overwrite my local changes?

Tags: android, git, frameworks, rom, repo

When I do some changes locally into /framework/base and then I type `repo sync` (To be up-to-date with ROM changes), it will automatically overwrite my local changes..Imagine if I do 100 changes, should I re-do them again?
Is there a method for not overwriting them?
Thank you :)

Comment: `repo sync` does not overwrite local changes, so I don't think you're doing what you think you're doing. Can you give us a more detailed example of how you're using the command?

Comment: Okay so.
I did `repo sync` after doing `repo init` ecc of this: https://github.com/AOSPB/manifest ..From here everything is good. To precise, I'm not a Contributor of the repos. So I did some change locally to some files ..Obviously I can't commit them because I'm not a Contributor as I said. So after my changes, I want that the repo should be up-to-date..But whenever I `repo sync` it says that it will overwrite my local changes..And in fact it did it. But I don't want that, with `repo sync` every change is overwritten. I hope you understood me..Thanks :)

Comment: Corrected phrasing of question

Comment: Perhaps you have merge conflicts? Run `git status` to check. From the repo documentation, "If the project has already been synchronized once, then repo sync is equivalent to: `git remote update` `git rebase origin/<BRANCH>`"

Answer (score 1):

If you have uncommitted changes `repo` will not override them. If you have committed changes on a topic branch which does not exist on the remote, `repo` will checkout the manifest revision. If these commits are on a topic branch on the remote, `repo` will not touch these changes, unless you do `repo sync -d`.

So, if you do not have a remote you want to commit to, you can just use local branches. Then when you do `repo sync` the manifest revisions are checked out. Then you can simply do `repo forall [<PROJECT_LIST>] -c <checkout my local topic branch>`.